# How do I add a confirmation message to Happy.js upon submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Happy.js and would like to show a message in a span/p element which will appear below the submit button when the user successfully fills out the form. I have the validation working, But can't seem to hook in the showing of the message. I tried my hand at it below, in the unhappy function! Thanks in advance...

```
 <p>
    <input type="submit" class="submit myButtons submitButton specificLink button button-block button-rounded button-large" name="submit" value="Submit" placeholder="">
 </p>

 <div id="results" class="results" style="text-align:center;">
    <span>
    <p class="success">Your message was sent succssfully!<br> I will be in touch as soon as I can.
    </p>
   </span>
 </div>

  var dd= $.noConflict();
  dd(document).ready(function () {
    dd('.success').hide();
        dd('#frmContact').isHappy({
            fields: {
              // reference the field you're talking about, probably by `id`
              // but you could certainly do $('[name=name]') as well.
              '#yourName': {
                required: true,
                message: 'Might we inquire your name'
              },
              '#email': {
                required: true,
                message: 'How are we to reach you sans email??',
                test: happy.email // this can be *any* function that returns true or false
              },
              '#comments': {
                required: true,
                message: 'Please leave a message!',
              }
          },
        unHappy: function () {
            var yourName = dd('#yourName').val();
            var email = dd('#email').val();
            var comments = dd('#comments').val();
            if (yourName && email && comments == true){
                  dd('.success').show();
            } 
        },
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
    function () {
    var yourName = dd('#yourName').val();
    var email = dd('#email').val();
    var comments = dd('#comments').val();
        if (yourName && email && comments == true){
            dd('#results').show();
            dd('.success').show();
        }
```